# How to save kafka data into different location based on a column value in spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a usecase in which I am consuming data from Kafka using spark structured streaming. I have multiple topics to subscribe and based on the **topic** name the dataframe should be dumped to a defined  location(different location for different topics). I saw if this can be solved using some kind of split/filter function in spark dataframe but could not find any.

As of now I am only subscribed to one topic and I am using my own written method to dump the data into a location in parquet's format. Here is the code I am currently using :

```
def save_as_parquet(cast_dataframe: DataFrame,output_path: 
      String,checkpointLocation: String): Unit = {
  val query = cast_dataframe.writeStream
              .format("parquet")
              .option("failOnDataLoss",true)
              .option("path",output_path)
              .option("checkpointLocation",checkpointLocation)
              .start()
              .awaitTermination()
 }
```

When I will be subscribed to different topics, then this cast_dataframe will also have values from different topics. I wish to dump the data from a topic to only the location it is assigned location. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka) `Dataset` to be written might contain optional `topic` column, which can be used for message routing:

> * The topic column is required if the “topic” configuration option is not specified.
>
> The value column is the only required option. If a key column is not specified then a null valued key column will be automatically added (see Kafka semantics on how null valued key values are handled). If a topic column exists then its value is used as the topic when writing the given row to Kafka, unless the “topic” configuration option is set i.e., the “topic” configuration option overrides the topic column.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation each Row from Kafka source has the following schema:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| key | binary |
| value | binary |
| topic | string |
| ... | ... |

Assuming you are reading from multiple topics using the source option

```
val kafkaInputDf = spark.readStream.format("kafka").[...]
  .option("subscribe", "topic1, topic2, topic3")
  .start()
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "topic")
```

you can then apply a filter to on the column `topic` to split the data accordingly:

```scala
val df1 = kafkaInputDf.filter(col("topic") === "topic1")
val df2 = kafkaInputDf.filter(col("topic") === "topic2")
val df3 = kafkaInputDf.filter(col("topic") === "topic3")
```

Then you can sink those three streaming Dataframes `df1`, `df2` and `df3` into their required sinks. As this will create three in parallel running streaming queries it is important that each `writeStream` get its own checkpoint location.